# Special character (%) in language string

Tags: language, jtext

I want to output a float price using a language constant like this:

```
MYCONST_VAT="incl. %.2f&#37 VAT"
```

So doing this:

```
echo Text::sprintf('MYCONST_VAT', 19);
```

outputs:

```
incl. 19.00% VAT
```

The problem is if sending Joomla mails using constants like that, the mails display the output like this:

```
incl. 19.00&#37 VAT
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the entity and also such string would need to be run through `html_entity_decode()`. However, the correct and much simpler way to escape the `%` character in `sprintf()` is using the `%` character:

```
MYCONST_VAT="incl. %.2f%% VAT"
```

Comment: That was the first thing i did, but then i get the error, a second argument is missing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Are you sure you used `%%` correctly?